# Unable to add foreign key constraint due to obscure conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, conflict

Trying to run :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD
CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_ScenarioResult] 
FOREIGN KEY ([ScenarioResultID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ScenarioResult] ([ScenarioResultID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Getting this error :

**Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Table1_ScenarioResult". The conflict occurred in database "8362", table "dbo.ScenarioResult", column 'ScenarioResultID'.**

I have checked :

- Constraint does not already exist, and no other exists on same column
- The values in the column match in both tables
- Types of columns are the same
- Tried a different name, also fails

On `SQL Server 2008 R2`

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461709/create-foreign-key-without-checking-existing-data

Comment: @Bulat I tried to put `NOCHECK` but did not know how to place it in above command, was giving me a syntax error if I place it before `CONSTRAINT`

Comment: example: ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exd WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT exd_check CHECK (column_a > 1) ;

Comment: can you post a query that you used to see if all values in foreign key match primary key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory this might work:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] WITH NOCHECK ADD
CONSTRAINT [FK_Table1_ScenarioResult] 
FOREIGN KEY ([ScenarioResultID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ScenarioResult] ([ScenarioResultID]) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Not sure how you checked for integrity of existing values, but it should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Orphans FROM [dbo].[Table1] t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ScenarioResult] WHERE ScenarioResultID = t.ScenarioResultID)
```

If "Orphans" is greater then zero you need to clean the data before adding a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This one was baffling me aswell, and then the penny dropped.

I was trying to create a Foreign Key using "Database Diagrams" in SQL Server 2012, but it refused to let me as it claimed to clash with the foreign key I was trying to create.  Huh ?

But, I had accepted the defaults to "**Enforce foreign key constraint**".  But I already had data in the two tables I was attempting to create a foreign key for, and it was breaking the foreign key rule I was trying to make, so SQL Server was rejecting the new key.

The solution (in this particular case) was to change "**Enforce foreign key constraint**" to "**No**", or at least until I had cleaned up my data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue
I clear the data of the tables where i want to edit the content and add a new foreign key constraint and retry. 
It works for me. 
I hope it help you.